# How to update automatically other fields when quantity on hand get increase or decrease odoo?

Tags: odoo, product, odoo-8, openerp-8, inventory

I need to update automatically this field(qty_available_onhand) either when quantity on hand get increase or decrease below i have mentioned my code.
Current below code working perfectly but only when i fill this field(squ_meter) as i'm entering in this field get multiplied to field(qty_avl) which is qty_avl is nothing but it is actually quantity on hand.
Any answer would be much appreciated

```
class product_template(osv.osv):
    _name = "product.template"
    _inherit = "product.template"
    _columns = {
         'squ_meter':fields.float('Square Meter'),
         'qty_available_onhand': fields.float(
             'Qty Sqm Available',
              compute='_compute_qty_available_onhand',
              require = True
          ),

         'qty_avl':fields.related(
             'virtual_available',
             relation='product.product',
             string='Quantity on Hand'
         ),
    }

    @api.depends('qty_avl', 'squ_meter')
    def _compute_qty_available_onhand(self):
        for record in self:
            record.qty_available_onhand = record.qty_avl * record.squ_meter
```

view.xml

```
<field name="name">product.product.inherited</field>
<field name="model">product.template</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='active']" position="after">
           <field name="qty_available_onhand"/>
           <field name="qty_avl" invisible='1'/>
           <field name="squ_meter"/>
   </xpath>
```

Comment: As I understood, you need to recalculate `qty_available_onhand` when you set new value to `squ_meter`? User must see new value in field? Is it right?

Comment: No danila my squ_meter's value will remain same but as the  qty_avl decrease then that decreased value of qty_avl get multiplied to same squ_meter which will equal to result of qty_available_onhand

Comment: I see that `qty_avl` it is related field. As I understand, `qty_available_onhand` can be updated using 2 ways. First - we change `squ_meter` on form `product.template`. Second - we change `virtual_available` on form `product.product`. When we change `squ_meter` or `virtual_available` you need to change value of 'qty_available_onhand' in db. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: yes danila you understood correctly but qty_available_onhand  should automatic change when qty_avl get change cause i don't want to change squ_meter's value

Comment: qty_avl is nothing but actually it's  field of quantity on like as the  product get sold  qty_avl automatically will decrease and that decreased value should get multiple to squ_meter

Comment: Try to add this method to your *ptoduct_template*: `@api.onchange('squ_meter')
    def onchange_squ_meter(self):
        self.qty_available_onhand = self.qty_avl * self.squ_meter`

Comment: At the same you can use `store=False` flag for calculated fields. Then Odoo will not add columns to table. Example: `'qty_available_onhand': fields.float(....., store=False)`